# removing Sametime status from Lotus notes status

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-sametime

How do I remove the sametime status (online, away, etc) from the inbox and mail addresses?

Lotus notes Release 8.5.2FP2 SHF75

I don't want to remove sametime, as I use that, but I don't want the status on the mail, nor on the mail recipents.
I don't have access to the server, or the document templates, so I don't know if I would have to put this in as a special request to the IT department, or if there's something I can set up on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302896), it can be set under `File > Preferences > Sametime > Server Community > Options tab "Use this server for status lookup"` but it does not work.

This actually worked for OP (running standard client), as outlined in [this IBM note](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/stwiki.nsf/dx/Optimizing_Name_Lookup_Clients):

Edit `plugin_customization.ini` file located under \framework\rcp\plugin_customization.ini and insert line `com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.people/liveNameResolverInternetFilter=non-existant-domain-name` (for details please see IBM document)

Comment: If there is only one server, then this setting has no effect. I've also tried setting `Use canonical names for status lookup` in an attempt to break it

Comment: Do you use basic or standard client?

Comment: anyway, try options listed in [Optimizing_Name_Lookup_Clients](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/stwiki.nsf/dx/Optimizing_Name_Lookup_Clients). Options differ for basic and standard clients. Important stuff is near the end of document. Please note for standard there is a hack to actually give non existent domain as the only one being looked up to effectively shut this functionality

Comment: Thank you - I'm evidently running the standard client. The non existent hack worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Sametime preferences called *Show instant messaging status*. Click that off and the inbox won't display the Sametime status.

*File » Instant Messaging » Preferences*. Then the *User Preferences* windows displays. In the window look at *General » Configuration* section. Un-check *Show instant messaging status for names* and click OK.

Make sure to close your inbox and then reopen it to see the changes take place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can disable the sametime awareness on the full client.  You can switch to the basic client (actions-->lotus notes-->switch to lite mode (basic)) and it will use the older style sametime client which has the preference to disable awareness. I believe the option is "Show instant messaging status for names" in the basic style sametime preferences.